# passing jQuery ui sortable variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I was wondering how or if it's possible to pass a variable from 'start:' to 'update:' in the function below, without making the variable global?

Thanks.

```
$('.type').sortable({
            placeholder: 'entityHighlight',
            cancel: '.disabled',
            opacity: 0.9,
            revert: true,
            scroll: true,
            start:function(event,ui) {
                startPos = ui.item.index();
            },
            update: function(event,ui) {
                var endPos = ui.item.index();
                var entityId = ui.item.attr('id');
                voteRank(entityId,startPos,endPos);
            }
        }).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use jQuery's [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) in `start` like this:

```
ui.item.data('startPos', ui.item.index());
```

and then read it in `update` like this:

```
voteRank(entityId, ui.item.data('startPos'), endPos);
```

(edited so you can actually use it now)

Comment: Score, even easier now. Thank You.